# Quotes in button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uibutton

How can I type in title of UIButton such quotes `<< >>`. I need for iOS 5 with Helvetica-Neue. Default i have `" "` quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unicode info for these characters is:

```
»
RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
Unicode: U+00BB, UTF-8: C2 BB

«
LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
Unicode: U+00AB, UTF-8: C2 AB
```

So to put one of these in a string, do this:

```
NSString* rightPointing = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xC2\xBB"];
NSString* leftPointing =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xC2\xAB"];
```

It seems a little cumbersome, but you can combine these strings with others, of course:

```
NSString* buttonLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", leftPointing, @"Button Title", rightPointing];
```

Comment: Did you try this? It gives `rightPointing = 슻`.

Comment: Damned. Fixed. Mixed up `\u` and `\x` escaping. That's what you get for editing code after copying.

Comment: @MartinR And with that, your solution becomes nicer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode and the compiler is fully Unicode-capable, so you can just enter the characters (if you have them on your keyboard):

```
NSString *title = @"«title»";
```

Alternatively, use the Unicode escape sequence:

```
NSString *title = @"\u00ABtitle\u00BB";
```